# Word for using commas in long numbers?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that means to use commas inside long numbers?

10000 vs 10,000

There's words like this in other languages разряд in Russian.

Comment: It is important to remember that different countries have different conventions in this regard. The Anglosphere uses a comma after every third digit from the right (not applicable to those to the right of the decimal point). And as one who earned his living as an accountant, and spent 4 decades staring at numbers, there is little in life more infuriating than people who present you with a swathe of figures that are not properly aligned, and with no commas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Delimiter](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark): (digit group separator)

> - For ease of reading, numbers with many **digits may be divided into groups using a delimiter**. In some countries, these "digit group separators" are only employed to the left of the decimal mark; in others, they are also used to separate long decimal numbers as well. An important reason for grouping is that it allows rapid judgement of the number of digits, via subitizing (telling at a glance) rather than counting – contrast 1,000,000,000 with 1000000000 for a (short) billion.

Comment: not quite, decimal mark is specific to seperating integer from fractional, a comma is more commonly (at least in USA) used to separate larger factors from smaller ones (1,000,000). I think the part about "digit grouping" is the right part.

Comment: Ok delmiter is good, I'll accept it but you're still linking to decimal mark wiki page

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer - it is on that page under 'digit grouping' heading!

Comment: ohh I see, can you add `#Digit_grouping` to the end of your URL?

Answer (score 3):

On many calculators it is referred to as "digit grouping".

Comment: I think you're right, but wish there was one word.